# How can I update the outdated Team Foundation Server file status icon in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

In visual studio 2010, under solution explorer the source control icons by the files denote that the file is currently checked out. However if I look at the file in the source control explorer it appears not to be checked out. I have tried the "refresh" button in solution explorer as well as "get latest version...". Neither update the status icon by the file. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try the 'Refresh Status' command available on the File > Source Control menu.  This command is also available on the 'Source Control - Team Foundation' toolbar if you have it showing.

Comment: I assumed this was the same as the refresh button in the solution explorer. Regardless it still did not work.

Comment: +1 - Worked like a charm for me. I'm using Serena Dimensions and had to Open From Source Control to get the bindings to set correctly though. Really wish we used TFS instead :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the file is checked out under another workspace?  If the Source Control Explorer (SCE), look in the "User" column for one of the files that appear checked out.  Does a user name (with a workspace name in parenthese) appear?  If so, then that user has the file checked out within the workspace listed.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2008 there was an issue with shelvesets: http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/marcelv/archive/2007/12/03/Team-Foundation-Server-2008-shows-incorrect-version-control-status-in-team-explorer-.aspx

Could this be the case for you too?

Comment: Thanks for the link but unfortunately that did not work. I tried deleting all the shelvesets for this solution and it still shows as checkout with the "person" status icon.